# Values are not geting cleared from ckeditor

Tags: jquery, html, css, ckeditor

Im having two popups. If i click Create button,one popup will open. Assume that 3 rowse are there in the popup.
a) Row 1 -> Firstname; Row2-> Lastname; Row3-> Email button
b) If i click on email button, it will open one more popup. In this popup im having CkEDITOR. So whatever im typing in this ckediotr and im storing this values in input hidden in first popup.
c) Then im clicking the submit button from the first popup and popup closes and redirect to index page. Values are storing properly in database as well.
Issues:
Once the values are stored in the database again im planning to create a new form, im clicking mail button and ckediotr will open. But previous values still present in the CKediotr. How to remove the existing values from the ckeditor?

```
       <form method="post" id='form'> 
        <textarea id="editor1" name="editor1"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="Save"/> 
        <script> $(document).ready(function(){ var test = localStorage.setValueInCkeditor_create; if(test!='' || test!='undefined') { CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.setData(test); }   $('#form').submit(function(){ window.parent.$("#create_ck_e‌​ditor").val(CKEDITOR‌​.instances.editor1.g‌​etData()); localStorage.setItem("setValueInCkeditor_create", CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.getData());
parent.$.colorbox.close(); return false; }); }); 
        </script>
```

Comment: <form method="post" id='form'>
<textarea id="editor1" name="editor1"></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Save"/>
<script>    
$(document).ready(function(){
var test = localStorage.setValueInCkeditor_create;
if(test!='' || test!='undefined') {
CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.setData(test);
} 
 $('#form').submit(function(){  window.parent.$("#create_ck_editor").val(CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.getData());
localStorage.setItem("setValueInCkeditor_create", CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.getData());
   parent.$.colorbox.close();
            return false;
        });       
    });
</script>

Answer (score 0):

`setData()` function will clear ckeditor

```
for ( instance in CKEDITOR.instances ){
    CKEDITOR.instances[instance].updateElement();
    CKEDITOR.instances[instance].setData('');
}
```

> You can create common function and call it on for submit event

```
function clearCke(){
    for ( instance in CKEDITOR.instances ){
        CKEDITOR.instances[instance].updateElement();
        CKEDITOR.instances[instance].setData('');
    }
}
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('#from').submit(function() {
        clearCke();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

After gave the below command in ajax done part, the problem is resolved

```
localStorage.removeItem("setValueInCkeditor_create");
```